Are questions about APA style on topic?
Recently, I've asked a question about the APA norms. It wasn't clear whether or not this was on topic. There's been another question about the APA-style.
I had the feeling nobody knows if it's on topic or not. So, what are the pro/contra-arguments? What will the community decide, is it allowed or not?

Since publication is an important part of research, I think that questions about the publication process should be in the scope of the site. As long as a certain citation style (or journal) is used in the field, question regarding this style (or journal) should be ok too. 
In general, I think that cogsci should be not too picky regarding possible topics as long as the lack of users and questions is the main problem of the site. Once the site is beyond the critical mass, the selection criteria can be raised at will (more or less).

Raised at the communities will, I'll note :)

Will is on the main site, there's no Will here ;)

@Ben Brocka: That was exactly what I meant. Thanks for clarifying, though. :)

Our closest competition in this regard, Writers.SE, only has 24 questions or answers that contain the term "APA".  However, I think with a critical mass of writing experts there, your questions might stand a better chance of getting an answer, despite it not being a popular topic.  
That being said, I don't have a problem with them being here, considering that there's only been 2 so far.  
I say, "yea" for the interim, but, in the case of newer users, we should provide people with a link to Writer's in the off-chance that they don't know about that site.  We could definitely use the questions, but so my only hesitancy is that a large influx of style matters could push more topical questions off of the front page.
